# how should i access a class variable from another class in python?

Tags: python, class, global-variables, class-variables

I have checked lots of websites and almost all questions related to the same on Stackoverflow. I cant find the solution to this problem. Its very important for a project. Please help. I want to use the variable self.email in Class A in the function email(self) in Class B. I've tried several things, but its not working. Inheritance wont work because its a kivy-python code and its already inheriting classes like GridLayout().

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self):
        ---some code---
    def email_id(self):
        self.email = x

Class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print(A().email)
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with using `A().email`?

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Can I declare an empty variable outside the class and then store the value in that? I tried it, but then the changes are not visible when I call the variable in the other class

Comment: Try: `tmp_a = A(); tmp_a.email_id(); print(tmp_a.email)`

Comment: `email` won't be accessible until you initialize it - which you do in `email_id`, so unless you call `email_id` on your `A()` it won't exist

Comment: but you should keep in mind that `A()` initializes a **separate** instance of `A`, so if you want to access the `email` field of a specific object you'll need to obtain a reference to it in `B`

Comment: Nothing's working. I also tried to declare an empty variable outside the classes, update it inside one of the functions, and use the updated variable in another class. but its not updating the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for are [property decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

```
Class A: 
    def __init__(self): 
        ---some code--- 
    @property
    def email(self): 
        return (some code to show the email)
```

Answer (score 0):

The field `email` of class `A` is created when `email_id()` is called.
Therefore, by the time `print(A().email)` is executed, this field is still not set.

You can set it first

```
Class B:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()
        a.email_id("email")
        print(a.email)
```